# Use setRoot vs setStackRoot

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

Guys who use wix navigation, can you explain when it is better to use `Navigation.setStackRoot()`, what is its advantage over regular `Navigation.setRoot()`

Answer (score 1):

- setRoot is used to change the whole layout of your app.
- setStackRoot is used to reset a single stack

For more details check the documentation:
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/docs/screen-api